# Cocoa animated frame in preference window

Tags: cocoa

Looking at many OSX application i often see preference window frame grow up and down depending on view contents activated by toolbar buttons.

I'd like to know if there's a way to automatize frame size dimension or if the only way is to resize and animate it programmatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can only use NSWindow's setFrame:display:animate: I don't think the windows can be sized automatically. So when you change the contents you can do something like this:

```
NSRect oldContentFrame = [oldContentView frame];
NSRect newContentFrame = [newContentView frame];

float widthDifference = oldContentFrame.size.width - newContentFrame.size.width;
float heightDifference = oldContentFrame.size.height - newContentFrame.size.height;

// Change the size of the window by the difference between the two views
// and move the frame up/down
NSRect windowFrame = [window frame];
windowFrame.size.width -= widthDifference;
windowFrame.size.height -= heightDifference;
windowFrame.origin.y += heightDifference;

// Remove the old content
[oldContentView removeFromSuperview];

// Change the size
[window setFrame:windowFrame display:YES animate:YES];

// Add the new view
[window setContentView:newContentView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`DBPrefsWindowController`](http://www.mere-mortal-software.com/blog/sourcecode.php) by Dave Batton. It allows you to do exactly what you want and almost all of the config is just done in Interface Builder.

Comment: I prefer at first try to create it myself :P

Comment: just for curiosity, the linked controller source not accessible anymore, do you know how to get a copy? TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Well You can use a library RHPreferencesWindowController. it is easy to use

> [RHPreferences](https://github.com/heardrwt/RHPreferences)